# C# : Sacar valores de un texto - indicando diferentes tags configurables de busqueda

Tags: c#, string, foreach, split

Actualmente ya he resuelto mi problema pero veo el resultado muy sucio con muchos split con muchos if , foreach no se si alguien me pueda orientar o si sabe una manera mas simple de realizarlo.

Ejemplo este es el string que recibo:
"
/Tag1Nombre
name         jesus
apellido     perez
edad         26
/Tag2DatosEscolares
universidad    unam
/tag3DatosEscolares/domicilio
domicilio     Ciudad universitaria
pais           Mexico
/tag4demas datos
fecha de nacimiento         01/01/1900
pais                        mexico
"
A si es el ejemplo del string que recibo y dependiendo de quien mande el string puede cambiar la estructura es decir los tags / y la nombre de la propiedad

Para hacerlo configurable cada cliente que me envia una peticion tiene un identificador y tengo guardado en config la configuracion de estos tags (/Tag1Nombre:name) y  nombre de las propiedades como envian en su string para poder extraerlas

el metodo que obtiene las propiedades del string y las asigna a un objeto dto es el siguiente

internal ResponseDto mapperInformationObjectDto(string textInformation, SourceDto tagsInformation)
{
var response = new ResponseDto();

```
        var name = tagsInformation.TagFindName.Split(':');

        var sectionsPlaneText = textInformation.Split(new string[] { String.Concat(Environment.NewLine,'/')},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var item in sectionsPlaneText)
        {
            if (item.Contains(String.Concat(name[0],Environment.NewLine)))
            {
                var sectionsValueName = (item.Split(Environment.NewLine));
                foreach (var itemInvoice in sectionsValueInvoice)
                {
                    response.Name = itemInvoice.Contains(String.Concat(name[1], " ")) ? (itemInvoice.Substring(name[1].Length).Trim()): null;
                    if (response.InvoiceNumber != null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

lo primero que hago es splitear los tags:propiedades configuradas en el config , luego spliteo todo el string a si obtengo todas las secciones a cada seccion las recorro y valido que inicien con el tag de donde tengo que sacar el valor, si coincide lo spliteo nuevamente para tener una lista de esa seccion donde obtengo un solo string con el dato (propiedad     valor) hago un nuevo forearch validando que exista la propiedad y cuando ya la encuentro le hago un substring con trim para obtener solo el valor y lo asigno al objetodto que devuelvo si tengo 4 casos aplica 4 veces el foreach

Alguien me puede orientar o dinciarme como lo puedo realizar de alguna manera mas sencilla?

Saludos

Comment: puedes colocar un ejemplo real de tu String? veo que haces una split con ":" pero no esta en el ejemplo que describes.

Comment: lo que pasa es que el split con : es para obtener los tags configurados en el config que es /Tag1Nombre:name a si obtengo en name[0] la etiqueta (/Tag1Nombre) y en name[1] la propiedad (name)

Comment: estas son las propiedades que entran al metodo string textInformation, SourceDto tagsInformation de las cuales textinformation es el string gigante y tagsinformation son los tags:propiedades a buscar dentro del string estos ultimos viene asi /Tag1Nombre:name los spliteo con : para que dentro del string primero busque el tag o cabecero /Tag1Nombre y cuando lo encuentre lo splitee y dentro de su arreglo de sta seccion busque la propiedad name